# BigQuery error when using wildcard in "select * from ..." only when executed on GCE VM

Tags: google-bigquery

I get an error from BigQuery when running a basic query with a wildcard:

```
bq query --use_legacy_sql=false "SELECT * FROM mydata.states LIMIT 10"
```

The problem is with the `*` - here is the error I get from bq when running it on the VM in GCE:

```
Error in query string: Error processing job '...': Field 'workspace' not found in table 'mydata.states'.
```

The "workspace" is the name of the directory in my current working directory - it appears that bq is expanding that (similar to `ls *`).

The same command works just fine in the `bq shell` without expanding `*` to the first directory it finds. The same query works perfectly fine on my local ubuntu outside of GCE.

If I list columns explicitly it works fine. I can't figure out what makes `bq` to replace `*` with the directory name in  my current path and  how to disable that?

I have two very similar machines running `bq` command line version 2.0.24 and both are ubuntu 14.04. Other than this, the * works in bash just as expected, including `set -f` that stops expansion all together, but it has no effect on `bq`...

The funny thing is that `*` works as expected when used in a query like this:

```
bq query --use_legacy_sql=false "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM mydata.states LIMIT 10"
```

The other odd thing is that this also works fine:

```
echo "SELECT * FROM mydata.states LIMIT 10" | bq query
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The BigQuery command line client does not expand the `*` itself; that's caused by Bash. The best long-term solution would be to put your query into a file, e.g. `my_query.sql`. Then you can do:

```
bq query --use_legacy_sql=false < my_query.sql
```

Now you don't need to worry about escaping any part of the query, since the query text is read from the file.

Comment: I agree this works and even `echo "$QUERY" | bq query` works, but I still do not understand what may cause the error on one Ubuntu OS and not have this problem on another Ubuntu machine...

Comment: It could be that you are using a different shell aside from Bash that causes the discrepancy. In any case, it's not caused by the BigQuery client. You might want to ask under a different StackOverflow tag.